# How to delete all the folder except one folder and its content using command prompt?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Say for example I have a folder `abc` containing sub folders `1`, `2`,  `3`, `4`. Now I want to delete all the folders except folder `2` and its content. I have tried

```
PUSHD (c:\abc\2) 
rd /s /q "C:\abc" 2>nul
```

But it deletes the files inside the `2` folder also. I don't want any of the files of folder `2` deleted?

Comment: Read the help text after typing `pushd /?` into a command prompt window; you will find that `pushd` changes the given directory to be the current one and nothing else...

Comment: @aschipfl the idea was probably "When I'm inside that folder, it can't be deleted"

Comment: @Stephan, so you have to be inside all sub-directories too and open all files?

Comment: I said that was probably the idea, not that it would work as intended :P Yes, to make it work, you'd have to "be inside all sub-directories too and open all files"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
for /D %%D in ("C:\abc\*.*") do (
    if /I not "%%~nxD"=="2" (
        2> nul rd /S /Q "%%~fD"
    )
)
```

The `for /D` loop walks through the directories `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`.
The `if` statement checks the name of the currently iterated directory not to be `2`.